# Artificially lowering CO2 concentration

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, air-quality

Is there any way to realistically lower CO2 concentration in living rooms?

Today only way to lower CO2 concentration is to basically bring the "fresh" air from the outside.

But this is always require energy to push, purify and heat/chill the air.
Maybe there is a more efficient way?

And what if "outside air" is already have hight CO2 concentration?

Comment: Have you looked at heat recovery or energy recovery ventilators that basically use outgoing air to preheat/prechill incoming air?

Comment: Something to remember is that the human breathing reflexes are driven by CO₂, not by oxygen. If you remove CO₂ and don't replace it with oxygen you introduce a very real risk of silent asphyxiation. Of course monitoring systems can be put in place to mitigate this but that is going to further drive up the cost.

Comment: plants. the faster growing, the better at capturing CO2. intensive weed growers have to add CO2 to the grow chamber so much is pulled from the air.

Comment: In most well maintain houses people breathing are the number one emitters of CO2(if higher than outside air).

Comment: Are you actually experiencing issues with CO2 building up to dangerous levels in your house, or is this a theoretical threat you're looking to eliminate? Usually, the concern is about CO levels, and they make detectors for that.

Comment: Why are you actually worried about CO2 build-up? It is about 0.04% of the air we breathe in, rising to 4% as we exhale. If you sealed yourself in a room for a day, you'd start to feel the effects - you'd feel short of breath, even though the oxygen levels would still be plentiful. In any normal house, just opening the front door to the postman once a day will be enough to re-balance that.

Comment: @PeterGreen: human breathing reflexes are driven by internal CO2 we generate.  We make CO2.  People breathe just fine in atmospheres devoid of CO2 (for example someone on 100% O2 nonrebreather) because these people are making CO2.   Blowing off body CO2 by hyperventilatng and raising body pH will depress respiratory drive which is a trick for long breath-holding.

Answer (score 7):

Bunch of grow lights and a vat of algae (or some other plant, but it's hard to beat algae for efficiency at getting the job done, albeit while not being as multi-use as a plant you'd actually eat.)

There are also plenty of chemical means, just dig out any submarine or spacecraft operators manual in the "emergency supplies" section.

Air exchange is more energy efficient than either of those in most cases where there is access to air.

I suppose you could try pulling it out via refrigeration, or compressing air and fractional distillation, but that's a tall order, and energy intensive as well.

Comment: By chemical means, perhaps some sodium hydroxide formulation (like an air filter) would do the trick? I'm just guessing 2NaOH + CO2 --> Na2CO3 + H2O

Comment: @ManRow but as Peter Green says in the comments, a CO2 scrubber that doesn't give O2 will end up with depleted oxygen which is bad

Comment: *Air exchange is more energy efficient than either of those* and the way to improve the efficiency of air exchange is heat exchangers so the outgoing warm air warms the incoming cold air.  Whole-house systems exist, as do extractor fans.  Of course the heat exchange isn't 100% efficient either